# Updating a subdoc array in Mongoose without getting the parent

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Schema:

```
var viewSchema = new Schema({
    active: Boolean
    , path: String
})

var pageSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
    , desc: String
    , url: String
    , views: [viewSchema]
})
```

In order to add a new view to an existing page I am doing:

```
Page
    .findOne({ id: pageId })
    .exec(function (err, page) {
        page.views.push({ path: path })
        page.save(function(err) {
           //saved
        })
    })
```

Is there a way to do the same without actually getting the page?

```
Page.update({ id: pageId }
          , { SOMETHING }
          , function(err){ 
             //updated 
          })
```

Comment: Have you looked at [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) this will allow you to find the document and update values in it in one operation.

Comment: is there an example of `fireAndModify` used in Mongoose to do something similar? thank you

Comment: The way I would do it is to try the command in the mongo shell, once it is working for you there you should be able to transfer it almost identically to mongoose.

Comment: Looking at the mongoose [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html) you should actually be fine with what you are proposing: `Page.update({ _id: id }, { $push: { "page.views": path }}, callback);`

Comment: Does not work:
`Page.update({ _id: page.id},{ $push: { "page.views": { path: "#page", active: true } } })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works..

```
Page.update({ _id: page.id},{ $push: { "views": { path: "#page", active: true } } })
```

thanks @Alistair-Nelson